# How to drag and drop HTML list items in a form and change their hidden input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, draggable

I have been looking around for a comprehensive 'easy-to-understand' solution to this problem, but haven't been able to find anything. My knowledge of JavaScript is limited, so please be easy on me! :)

```
<form name="xyz" action="/scripts/change-position.php">
    <ul>
        <li draggable="true">Item A <input type="hidden" name="position" value="1"></li>
        <li draggable="true">Item B <input type="hidden" name="position" value="2"></li>
        <li draggable="true">Item C <input type="hidden" name="position" value="3"></li> 
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save new order">
</form>
```

1. how do I make my list items sortable?
2. how do I update the value of each li's hidden input field to reflect the new order?
3. I am already using jQuery on the page where I need to insert the form, so pure JavaScript of jQuery would be preferable.
4. not a must, but the solution should ideally work on mobile devices.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are Welcome, `jQueryUI` sortable. I use update event to change position value of hidden inputs. Update event is triggered when the user stopped sorting and the DOM position has changed.

**Update**

added `jqueryui-touch-punch` to support touch events

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var list = $('#mySortable'),
      updatePosition = function() {
        list.children().each(function(i, e){
          $(this).children('input[type="hidden"]').val(++i);
        });
      };

  list.sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: updatePosition
  });
});
```

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li,
.ui-state-highlight {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 2.5em;
 max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.ui-state-highlight{
 display: block;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>


<form name="xyz" action="/scripts/change-position.php">
    <ul id="mySortable">
        <li draggable="true">Item A <input type="hidden" name="position" value="1"></li>
        <li draggable="true">Item B <input type="hidden" name="position" value="2"></li>
        <li draggable="true">Item C <input type="hidden" name="position" value="3"></li> 
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save new order">
</form>
```